# Scale invariance and state equation for fluid dynamics

Tags: scale-invariance

I am trying to understand the example provided in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance#Other_examples_of_scale_invariance) of the Wikipedia article on scale invariance. In particular where it says

> In order to deduce the scale invariance of these equations we specify an equation of state, relating the fluid pressure to the fluid density

The state equation used is
$$ P = c_s ^2 \rho$$

**Q:** Why such  specification of the state equation is necessary and why that particular choice ensures the scale invariance?

Thanks

Comment: To choose an equation of state has nothing to do with scale invariance, you simply always need it to close your system of equations. Otherwise P remains an unknown, without its own governing equation  (if you don't use an energy equation).

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisionEscape , does it mean that any equation added to solve the system is enough? I mean any $p(\rho)$ or $p(v)$ or $v(\rho)$ etc (supposing that those functions have physical meaning)

Comment: Any $P(\rho,v)$ is needed, otherwise not every quantity on the right-hand sides of mass and momentum conservation equations are known.